# Best way to find the angle between two nodes in an lattice graph?

Tags: c++, math, graph

If I have a lattice graph which looks like this:

```
0:0 0:1 0:2 0:3
1:0 1:1 1:2 1:3
2:0 2:1 2:2 2:3
3:0 3:1 3:2 3:3
```

, what is the best way to find an angle between two nodes?
Example:

```
angle(0:0, 0:1) = 0;
angle(0:0, 1:1) = 45;
```

This will be used during rendering to visualize a path in this graph with lines, a line will be placed at the center of a node and then rotated to end in the next node on the path. Currently I hardcoded every coordinateS difference and match it to the corresponding angle with a switch statement, are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming x:y format, and an angle measured clockwise from the horizontal:

```
angle(x1:y1, x2:y2) = arctan((x2-x1)/(y2-y1))
```

Comment: The usual formula is `std::atan ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))`. But practically, it is generally much more convenient to use `std::atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)`. See [std:atan2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2).

Comment: @Damien, Andrew, would this still work with y:x format?

Comment: @aa The format `y:x` is not C++. What is usual for example is to create a `struct Point {double x,y;};`

Comment: 90 degrees has an issue, sorry.  so these ned to be exceptioned out, so-to-speak